# Remove Duplicates from Sorted Array return problem

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Q)26 in leetcode problem :
Given an integer array nums sorted in non-decreasing order, remove the duplicates in-place such that each unique element appears only once. The relative order of the elements should be kept the same. Then return the number of unique elements in nums.

Consider the number of unique elements of nums to be k, to get accepted, you need to do the following things:

Change the array nums such that the first k elements of nums contain the unique elements in the order they were present in nums initially. The remaining elements of nums are not important as well as the size of nums.
Return k.

```
class Solution(object):
    def removeDuplicates(self, nums):
     #Removing duplicates

        nums=(list(dict.fromkeys(nums)))

#counting the length of the new list

        k= len(nums)
        return  k
```

I removed all duplicates then counted the number of elements in the list (they all unique numbers ) and returned the value of k. What is the issue that when I run my code it returns wrong answer ?

Comment: You're not changing the value of the `nums` array that you passed to `removeDuplicates`. See the dupe for an explanation